# Devexpress GridControl immediate refresh when value has been changed

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, refresh, gridcontrol

I tried to search for the answer in other posts, however nothing seems to be solution to my problem.

So, I have 2 GridControls connected to one database with Remarks. First GridControls is showing inactive remarks (ones that has not been added to the quote yet) second GridControls showing active remarks (remarks already in us, default ones as well as those added from the first GridControls).

I'm using RepositoryItemCheckEdit to decide which remarks to add, ones that are checked are active, unchecked ones are not active.

Everything is working fine, when I select inactive remark and check RepositoryItemCheckEdit it goes to Active GridControl, however it's not being moved immediate, I need to click somewhere else for it to move over. What I want is for the remark to become active straight away instead of checking the box and clicking somewhere else for it to move.

Here is the code I used to refresh Grid:

```
Private Sub RepositoryItemCheckEditActive_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemCheckEditActive.CheckedChanged
        RemarkActiveView.RefreshData()
        RemarksMainView.RefreshData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RepositoryItemCheckEditUnActive_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemCheckEditUnActive.CheckedChanged
        RemarksMainView.RefreshData()
        RemarkActiveView.RefreshData()
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Patryk

Comment: Have you tried just Refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my friend just found out the solution.

In case someone else is wondering how to do it here is the code:

```
Private Sub RepositoryItemCheckEditActive_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemCheckEditActive.MouseUp
        If RemarksInactiveMainView.FocusedColumn Is colInActiveInUse Then
            RemarksInactiveMainView.CloseEditor()
            RemarkActiveMainView.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
Private Sub RepositoryItemCheckEditInActive_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemCheckEditInActive.MouseUp
    If RemarkActiveMainView.FocusedColumn Is colActiveInUse Then
        RemarkActiveMainView.CloseEditor()
        RemarksInactiveMainView.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Focus had to get changed for the results to move immediately.

Thanks